# Accessibility bus warning when opening files in Eclipse from command line (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: command-line, eclipse

Similar to closed issue [Gnome Menu Broken?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430230/gnome-menu-broken)

When opening a file from the command line for edits in Eclipse , I get this warning:

```
** (eclipse:nnnn): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: 
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application 
did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, 
the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

The 4-digit number at (eclipse:nnnn) changes each time I issue an 'eclipse some/file.ext' command. The file opens but the warning is an annoyance that shouldn't be happening, it may be indicative of some other problem. Updated Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, updated Eclipse Luna.

Comment: When launching gedit from the command line:

$ gedit

   ** (gedit:12895): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit 
   repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource'
   , version '3.0' not found

and yet, gedit launches. After Ubuntu pukes out this annoying warning.

Answer (score 7):

Summary of workaround: Add "export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1" to your .bashrc/.bash_profile/etc.

Details: I have this annoying issue too. Obviously, it's a bug that needs to be fixed, but as an end user, I found a workaround at a Fedora bug thread: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1056820. The workaround is to add "export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1" to my environment (via .bashrc/.bash_profile/etc, or similar equivalent command if you're not using bash). Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked (`export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1`) in Kubuntu 14.04. I got the message: `** (emacs:9112): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-fKkYD0nn7f: Connection refused` each time I opened Emacs in KDE.. (Background: I installed Kubuntu desktop, and it worked fine in Unity, but not in KDE). Thanks!